# El atributo get.() no cambia al hacer click en checkbox

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor de la variable `confirmacion_var=tk.BooleanVar()` que debería obtener el valor `True` al dar click en el pero sigue como `False` a pesar de dar click.
Este es el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry('700x700')
ventana.title("PYTHON GARABATOS")


confirmacion_var=tk.BooleanVar()
chk_confirmacion=Checkbutton(ventana, text="SI/NO", variable=confirmacion_var)
chk_confirmacion.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
#chk_confirmacion.select()
print(confirmacion_var.get())


ventana.resizable(False, False)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable si cambia, el problema es que cuando pones:

```
print(confirmacion_var.get())
```

este imprime el valor por defecto de `confirmacion_var` que es `False` y solo se ejecuta una vez por lo cual no puedes ver el cambio al presionar el botón.

Proba este código

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk

ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('700x700')
ventana.title("PYTHON GARABATOS")

confirmacion_var=tk.BooleanVar()
#button checked
confirmacion_var.set(True)

chk_confirmacion=ttk.Checkbutton(ventana, text="SI/NO", variable=confirmacion_var)
chk_confirmacion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

tk.Button(ventana, text="Mostrar",
          command=lambda:(ms.showinfo(title="Aviso",
                          message="%s" %confirmacion_var.get()))
                          ).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

ventana.resizable(False, False)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos.